# How do I make an async method return Task<IEnumerable<T>>?

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

I am currently refactoring a method that has the async keyword but does not use await, thus running synchronously.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Obj>> SearchObj(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return _db.Objects;

        return _db.Objects.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.SomeProperty.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
```

How do I modify this method so that it runs asynchronously? Is it even necessary to run this asynchronously given a large dataset?

I have tried using the AsAsyncEnumerable() method but am not sure how to execute the Where() filter on an IAsyncEnumerable object.

Comment: avoid using `AsEnumerable` - you are forcing a full fetch of the table

Answer (score 2):

`AsEnumerable` is not async method and it is needed to use `ToListAsync`, `ToArrayAsync` before returning `IEnumerable`.
Also note that `.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` overload translation is not supported. Just use `.Contains(value)`, if default collation in database is case insensitive, it will work by default.

```cs
private Task<IEnumerable<Obj>> SearchObj(string value)
{
    var query = _db.Objects.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        query = query.Where(x => x.SomeProperty.Contains(value));

    return query.ToListAsync();
}
```

If dtabase/column collation is not case insitive, you have to upper/lower case string values:

```cs
private Task<IEnumerable<Obj>> SearchObj(string value)
{
    var query = _db.Objects.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        value = value.ToUpper();
        query = query.Where(x => x.SomeProperty.ToUpper().Contains(value));
    }

    return query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I agree with the async approach, but you are changing the filter criteria, thus eventually breaking functionality (why it is used in the first place?). So what is your solution if the database collation is *not* case insensitive?